# Find exact value with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has a hidden column that contains ids. I use the value in this column and send it to the server so I can grab the correct record.

I am not using datatables.net and I allow the user to update the row. So they click on an edit button and a dialog pops up and they edit it. Once they hit update I send all the values back including the id(stored in a hidden text field).

So I need to update the datatable and the fast way I found is use a plugin for it that allows you to take an html row and pass it to the datatable(instead of passing each column value in an array).

So first I need to delete the row then add the newly update row.

I have one problem though I don't know how to figure out which row to delete.

I could have some global variable that would store the row object and when it is time to delete it use that object. However I really don't want to do this as I don't want a global variable just flying around if I can help it.

So the hidden column with the value has a class name that I use as a slector(class ="hidden").

So I am wondering how could I do a search to filter down to only table cells that have this class name, has the exact value(say 55 that I can use from the hidden textbox).

I was thinking of using jquery contains but that might get stuff that might have that number. I want an exact match.

Comment: What server side environment do you use? It sounds like .Net. If so, can you please add a tag for that.

Comment: Is the value just text in the `td`, or some kind of `input`?

Comment: You could store the database ID in the tr element's id, eg. `<tr id="record_NNN">`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
$('td.hidden:contains("55")')
```

This will find any `td` of `class` 'hidden' that contains the string '55', this is slightly problematic since it will *also* match the string '555', '055' etc.

---

**Edited** to refine the above a little, to make it specific to the required value:

```
$('td.hidden:contains("55")').filter(
    function(){
        return $(this).text() == '55';
    }).closest('tr').addClass('highlight');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AsSDQ/).

Revised [JS Fiddle demo, allowing searching](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AsSDQ/1/).

While `filter()` would work perfectly well *without* the `:contains()` pseudo-selector I retained the `:contains()` in order to reduce the number of elements that jQuery has to work through.

References:

- [`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, something like

```
 $('body').find('.hidden').filter(function(elem) { ... } ).remove();
```

with whatever appropriate test in `...`.